# Prove that $ |a_{n+k} - a_{n}| \leq \frac{\gamma^{n-1}}{1-\gamma} |a_{2} - a_{1}|$ for all $ k,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Assuming that $ 0 \leq \gamma \lt 1$ and a series $ a_{n}$ of real numbers with the property for all natural numbers  $n \geq 2 : \\  |a_{n+1}-a_{n} | \leq \gamma \space |a_n - a_{n-1}|$

I have shown that this series $a_n$ definietly converges in $\mathbb{R}$ but i am unable to prove the inequality.

I guess that i need to show this using induction and the Triangle inequality. The fraction $\frac{\gamma^{n-1}}{1-\gamma}$ reminds me of the Geometric series.

I don't know how to proceed. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint: $|a_{n+k}-a_n| = |\sum_{j=1}^k a_{n+j} - a_{n + j-1}| \le \sum_{j=1}^k |a_{n+j} - a_{n+j-1}| \le \sum_{j=1}^k \gamma^{j-1} |a_{n+1}-a_n|$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you very much! The only thing i don't get is your last inequality. My guess is that it is true because i could show that $|a_{n+1}−a_n|≤ \gamma^n |a_1−a_0|$. Do i have the right hunch?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can prove inductivelly the last inequality, that is $|a_{n+j}-a_{n+j-1}| \le \gamma^{j-1}|a_{n+1}-a_n|$.